# No graphical effects in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: radeon, hybrid-graphics, hardware-acceleration

I have recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 via wubi inside windows on my laptop.

I get standard graphics at start. But when I install the graphical driver through the additional drivers it installs the main driver, but update installation fails.

Then I can't see 3D effects too.

I can't find a solution for this.

I have intel i5 3210m with intel HD 4000 graphic card with AMD Radeon HD7670M 1 GB in switchable mode.

I need to know how to enable the eye candy on my laptop.

I just miss ubuntu without it. Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to install the graphic drivers from the AMD website.

Link to download the drivers: http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/Pages/index.aspx